# Compact Hermitian nilpotent operator implies zero operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ be a compact, Hermitian operator. Prove that if $A^n=0$ for some $n$, then $A=0$.

I'm not sure where to start on this question, and I'm having trouble seeing how I can exploit the fact that $A$ is Hermitian. Any help or hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Diagonalize and use the fact that nilpotent implies all of the eigenvalues are 0!

Comment: However I'm not sure one needs compactness - one could also use the $C^*$ identity that $\|A\|^2 = \|AA^*\| = \|A^2\|$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is a bounded Hermitian operator on a Hilbert space $H$, and further suppose that $A^n=0$ for some $n$. If $n$ is even then $A^{n/2}=0$ because
$$
              0=\langle A^n x,x\rangle=\|A^{n/2}x\|^2,\;\;\; x\in H.
$$
If $n > 1$ is odd, then $A^{n+1}=0$, which gives $A^{(n+1)/2}=0$.

Repeating this argument through finite induction leads to the conclusion that $A=0$